# Is this a correct FSM graph?

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines, sequence-detector

This question is sourced from H. Roth's book 'Fundamentals of Logic Design.' It pertains to a sequential circuit featuring a single input (X) and one output (Z). The circuit's function entails examining sets of four consecutive inputs, with the output Z being equal to 1 when the input sequence 0101 or 1001 is detected. Notably, the circuit undergoes a reset operation after processing every four inputs. The task at hand involves the determination of the Mealy state graph for this specific circuit.

[image]

Is this a correct path (highlighted in pink color)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the pink highlighted path is valid.

Since the FSM resets every 4 inputs, an input sequence which begins with 1-1 does not match your required input sequences and will keep the output as 0.  Once you enter state \$S_5\$, you guarantee the output remains 0.